# Getting a weird reaction while using .pop()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing some practice work and I am tasked with removing the first number from a string until it is odd.

> The function should remove elements from the front of lst until the front of the list is not even. The function should then return lst.
>
> For example if lst started as `[4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]`, then delete_starting_evens(lst) should return `[11, 12, 15]`.

```py
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
  for i in lst:
    if i % 2 == 0:
      lst.pop(0)
    else:
      break
  return lst

print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 6, 6, 6, 10, 11, 12, 15]))

print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10]))
```

---

```py
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
  for i in lst:
    if i % 2 == 0:
      lst = lst[1:]
    else:
      break
  return lst

print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 6, 6, 6, 10, 11, 12, 15]))

print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10]))`
```

The code works as intended if i use `lst = lst[1:]`,
but I do not understand why the `lst.pop(0)` version does not work. It will work for a few iterations, but then no longer pops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying a list while iterating over it is usually a recipe to get weird results. Try printing `lst` and `i` at every iteration and you'll see what's going on... (Try with `lst = [2,4,6,8,10,...]` to make it clearer...)

Here's one safe way to do it:

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        if x % 2 != 0:
            break
    else:
        return []
    return lst[i:]
```

Note that `pop` mutates your list, while `lst = lst[1:]` reassigns it.

If efficiency matters:

```
def f():
    lst = list(range(0,10000,2))+[3,0,2,4,6]
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        if x % 2:
            break
    else:
        return []
    return lst[i:]

def g():
    lst = list(range(0,10000,2))+[3,0,2,4,6]
    while lst and lst[0] % 2 == 0:
        lst.pop(0)
    return lst

%timeit f()
# 334 µs ± 2.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit g()
# 2.09 ms ± 12.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: A much simpler solution is `while lst[0] % 2 == 0: lst.pop(0)`

Comment: (you actually need to check for `while lst and lst[0] % 2 == 0` to be safe...)

Comment: Thanks, good point. Or make it an entry condition: `if lst: while lst[0] % 2 == 0:`

Comment: `list.pop(0)` is an O(n) operation, so I don't recommend doing it in a loop. Your posted solution is way better.

Comment: @ggorlen yes I was going to post about it, but I had a bug in my comparison test which was wrongly showing the opposite :). Now fixed and added.

Comment: FYI, there's a builtin that comes with itertools that is worth mentioning: `itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, lst)`. You might consider editing your post on the benchmark to explain why `.pop(0)` is so slow (moves all the elements in the list down every time).